# Efficiency : UUID vs int comparison in Java

Tags: java, uuid

Excuse if this is a too simple question.

Consider the following class:

```
public class Asset {
   private int id;
   private UUID uuid;
}
```

If I'm to check the equality of a large number of Asset objects based on their Id, which is more efficient in terms of performance, id vs uuid?

Comment: why don't you try it and see.

Comment: Define "large number".  If it's less than, say, 100,000,000 the performance _difference_ will likely be minimal.  In other words, don't worry about it unless you have hard evidence from profiling that this comparison is causing performance problems.  Premature optimization and all that...

Comment: The [Answer by Chaurasia](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42571827/642706) seems correct and precise. More generally, you would not choose between an `int` and a `UUID` based on performance. Practically speaking, either you need to track the identity of an object across time and space (space meaning multiple software and/or hardware systems) and use an `UUID`, or you need to track an object briefly within a small scope and use an `int` (or a `UUID` just for the heck of it, or maybe future-proofing).

Comment: yeah records can be  ~100,000,000. Okay got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asymptotically both are constant time `O(1)` comparisons. 
`UUID` maintains **most significant 64 bits** and **least significant 64 bits** and compares them. Here is the `equals()` method.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if ((null == obj) || (obj.getClass() != UUID.class))
        return false;
    UUID id = (UUID)obj;
    return (mostSigBits == id.mostSigBits &&
            leastSigBits == id.leastSigBits);
}
```

And Integer equality is also constant time.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Integer) {
        return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

But it should be noted that `UUID` comparison includes comparison of 2 `long` type of fields.

**EDIT:** thanks  Chai T. Rex for mentioning that question asks about `int`
So the equality of two `int` is again straightforward(==) and constant time.

Comment: One small thing: the question uses `int`s rather than `Integer`s